# How to Selecting 2 query to single statment?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two select statement for find avg economy for car I need connect to single statement. I tired but showig error

Basically in first statement includes cast, avg, nullif groupby 
In second statement contains where, when, case then

```
SELECT  vehicle_id,CAST(AVG((NULLIF(economy,0))) AS int) FROM fillups group BY vehicle_id
WHERE vehicle_id <= 2 THEN 'Prius'
AND
vehicle_id >= 2 THEN 'Other';
```

Thats the code when put into single statement

Comment: You sure you are using MySQL?? Because `CAST(<expression> AS INT)` isn't a thing in MySQL, it's `CAST(<expression> AS UNSIGNED)` or `CAST(<expression> AS SIGNED)` to cast to a `INT` in MySQL ..  i assume you use SQL Server (MSSQL) instead off MySQL?

Comment: Hi. Where are your two statements? What errors are you getting? What data is being returned currently, and what data are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: Also the `WHERE` clause should go infront off the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
Select vehicle_id, CAST(AVG((NULLIF(economy,0))) AS int),
when vehicle_id < 2 then 'Prius'
when vehicle_id >= 2 then 'other'
from fillups
group by vehicle_id
```

This may help !!

If not please mention some data schema structure.

Comment: This will also error..  `WHEN .. THEN ..` clauses in any SQL database requires to be in a `CASE END` clause

Comment: (#1.) SELECT  vehicle_id,CAST(AVG((NULLIF(economy,0))) AS int) FROM fillups group BY vehicle_id;

(#2.) SELECT
CASE
WHEN vehicle_id <= 2 THEN 'Prius'
WHEN vehicle_id >= 2  THEN 'Other'
END AS vehicle_ids
FROM fillups;

I need to connect 1 & 2 together. Could you give me any hints please

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```sql
Select vehicle_id, CAST(AVG((NULLIF(economy,0)) as int) as columnA,
       case when vehicle_id < 2 then 'Prius'
            when vehicle_id >= 2 then 'other'
       end as columnB
from fillups
group by vehicle_id
```

Comment: @ArJuNMangal Please accept any response you like to close this issue.